# Pygame get information about mouse ball

Tags: pygame, mouse

Is there a way of getting information about the mouse ball, so if its being rolling up or down. Using `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` or `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN / UP` gives only information about being the mouse clicked but not about the ball scrolling.

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pygame/2355

Comment: Do you mean the 'Scroll Wheel' or the 'Mouse Ball' used in older mice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each mouse button event can be called from the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN events button attribute. Including left/right/middle click and scroll up/scroll down

Example:

```
import pygame as py

py.init()

window = (400,400)
screen = py.display.set_mode(window)

clock = py.time.Clock()

done = False
while not done:
    for event in py.event.get():
        if event.type == py.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == py.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 4:
                print "scrolled up"
            elif event.button == 5:
                print "scrolled down"
    clock.tick(30)

py.quit()
```

This looks for pressed mouse buttons in the active window and prints upon a scroll up or down